# Javascript : A speed Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an application that works out the speed by using the maths formula of distance / time.

I'm struggling to find the code that takes the time in the correct format from the three input boxes I've created. I get given the correct answer with hours input value but when i add on the minutes and seconds values it doesn't quite work. I know there's huge thing i'm missing with the time fields in my code but i can't quite figure out the solution to it. My code is below and i'd really appreciate a solution and even more, the logic behind the solution.:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Speed Calculator</h1>

    <div speedcalc>
        <label for="distance"><b>Distance:</b></label>
        <input type="number" id="distanceInput">
        <select>
        <option value="miles">Miles</option>
        <option value="kilometres">Kilometres</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="number"><b>Time</b></label>
    <label for="number">Hours: </label>
    <input type="number" id="hoursInput">
    <label for="number">Minutes: </label>
    <input type="number" id="minutesInput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="number">Seconds: </label>
    <input type="number" id="secondsInput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="averageSpeedBtn">Average Speed</button>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <p></p>


    </div>



        <script src="app.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
let distance = document.getElementById('distanceInput');
let hours = document.getElementById('hoursInput');
let minutes = document.getElementById('minutesInput');
let seconds = document.getElementById('secondsInput');

const distanceSelect = document.querySelector('select');

const averageSpeedBtn = document.getElementById('averageSpeedBtn');

const para = document.querySelector('p');


averageSpeedBtn.addEventListener('click', function speed() {


            let mile = distance.value;

            let time = hours.value + minutes.value + seconds.value;

            let formula = mile / time;

            para.textContent = 'average speed : ' + formula;

});
```

Comment: You can't just simply sum up hours, minutes and seconds. You should convert all of them to the same units. For example, to seconds: `let time = hours.value * 3600 + minutes.value * 60 + seconds.value`. Then you'll get the speed in miles per second. Or you can convert it to hours: `let time = hours.value + minutes.value / 60.0 + seconds.value / 3600.0`, then you'll get result in miles per hour

Comment: totally what @Alex says - but you also need to consider if you need to parse your values too - as i suspect let mile = distance.value; would be a string/text not float https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting right value is, the input value which you receive is a string, So you need to convert it into a number using parseInt like,

```
let time = (+hours.value) + (+minutes.value) + (+seconds.value)
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
let distance = document.getElementById('distanceInput');
let hours = document.getElementById('hoursInput');
let minutes = document.getElementById('minutesInput');
let seconds = document.getElementById('secondsInput');

const distanceSelect = document.querySelector('select');

const averageSpeedBtn = document.getElementById('averageSpeedBtn');

const para = document.querySelector('p');


averageSpeedBtn.addEventListener('click', function speed() {


            let mile = distance.value;

  
            let time = (+hours.value) + (+minutes.value) + (+seconds.value)

            let formula = mile / time;

            para.textContent = 'average speed : ' + formula;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Speed Calculator</h1>

    <div speedcalc>
        <label for="distance"><b>Distance:</b></label>
        <input type="number" id="distanceInput">
        <select>
        <option value="miles">Miles</option>
        <option value="kilometres">Kilometres</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="number"><b>Time</b></label>
    <label for="number">Hours: </label>
    <input type="number" id="hoursInput">
    <label for="number">Minutes: </label>
    <input type="number" id="minutesInput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="number">Seconds: </label>
    <input type="number" id="secondsInput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="averageSpeedBtn">Average Speed</button>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <p></p>


    </div>



        <script src="app.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eventhough your  question was about making the input string into number and **@Alex** point it out in comments, You could also consider the time as real time by making the time variable with following,

```
let time = (+hours.value) + (+minutes.value) / 60 + (+seconds.value) / 3600
```

> [**Working Codepen with time calculation**](https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/dyoLqNX)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option id="miles" value="miles">Miles</option>
<option id="kilometres" value="kilometres">Kilometres</option>
```

```
let dist = parseFloat(document.getElementById('distanceInput'));
let hr = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hoursInput'));
let min = parseFloat(document.getElementById('minutesInput'));
let sec = parseFloat(document.getElementById('secondsInput'));

const miles = document.getElementById("miles");
const kilometres = document.getElementById("kilometres");

const averageSpeedBtn = document.getElementById('averageSpeedBtn');

const para = document.querySelector('p');


averageSpeedBtn.addEventListener('click', function speed() {
  let distance = dist.value;
  let time = (hr.value * 3600 + min.value * 60 + sec.value) / 3600;
  let formula = distance / time;
  let averageSpeed = '';
  if (miles.selected) { averageSpeed = 'Miles' } else if (kilometres.selected) { averageSpeed = 'Kilometres' }
  para.textContent = 'average speed : ' + formula + averageSpeed;

});
```